# Creating a return link for a form with no database

Tags: php, session, encryption

Hello everyone and happy new year. 
I am building a form which is not allowed to have a database attached to it. This is fine as I am using session to store information needed to calculate figures etc...

My question is when a user wishes to return to the form. I need to be able to store the form data in the link to then load back into the users session, without the form data being obvious in the URL.

I have tried taking the session data then openssl encryption / decryption to achieve this, getting blank responses, presume this is something to do with URL characters? I have also tried MCRYPT and am getting strange characters.

The code ($string is always a json encoded array containing form information):

MCRYPT

```
$key = 'the password to work with';
$linkdata = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
```

open SSL version

```
$method = "AES-128-ECB";
$password = "the password to work with";
$linkdata = openssl_encrypt($string, $method, $password);
```

For decryption i do ($return_data is always the $_GET containing the encoded data):

MCRYPT

```
$key = 'the password to work with';
$decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($return_data), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
$_SESSION['hotel'] = $decrypted;
```

OpenSSL

```
$method = "AES-128-ECB";
$password = "the password to work with";
$linkdata = openssl_decrypt($return_data, $method, $password);
$_SESSION['hotel'] = $linkdata;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: *not allowed to have a database attached to it* — This is a really weird requirement — *I am using session to store information* — So you *do* have a database, it just isn't a relational database. You should check your requirements very carefully.

Comment: yes, sorry. By not allowed to have a database I mean i cant have permanent storage of the data. Once the form is complete the data is posted to our web service where its processed and a system is created from the information, but this only occurs on completion of the entire form. So i need a method of converting the session data to a url and back again

Comment: are u calling session_start() somewhere? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Yes, these are in a php file I use for all of the save/recall actions and session_start is at the top of the page, after <?php and before anything else

Comment: Where does $return_data come from? Query string? Post var?

Comment: Your openssl sequence is ok, but there is a missing link here from $linkdata to $return_data. What's going on there?

Comment: @Jack_McG can u try one thing, make it work without encyption. just store data in session and try to retrive it .what do u think?

Comment: @yivi the $return_data comes from a $_GET[''] variable in the url called data.

Comment: And how are you getting linkdata to that _GET variable? are you urlencoding before sending it? are you base64encoding it?

Comment: @user3522412 I can retrieve session data, encrypt it and decrypt it using MCRYPT its just that the session data then contains many weird characters, the form is fully functional its just this one element that is blocking its release at the moment.

Comment: @yivi on the MCYPT version it does base64 encode/decode
on the OpenSSL it does url_encode()/url_decode()

Comment: you don't need to url_decode _GET variables. and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: Again, code is missing. Post the missing parts.

Comment: it was the URL decode, have removed it and now the data seems to be populating back

Sorry for the confusion, should have spotted it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Albeit code is missing, everything points at you using `url_decode` on your `$_GET` data before decrypting.

`$_GET` variables come already url decoded, you shouldn't apply the function again, or you can (and apparently are) mess up your data.